Help request for calculating an integral
I am trying to calculate the following inntegral
$$\int \frac{2\sqrt{1- x^2}}{2 x\sqrt{1- x^2}+ 5}\, dx. $$
My attempt:
$$\int \frac{2\sqrt{1- x^2}}{2 x\sqrt{1- x^2}+ 5}\, dx = \frac{1}{x} - \int \frac{5}{2 x^2 \sqrt{1- x^2}+ 5x}\, dx, $$
and putting $x = \sin t$ the integral becomes
$$\int \frac{5 \cos t \, dt}{2\sin^2 t \cos t + 5\sin t} $$
Here I have faced with the problem!
Thanks for any helps.

It might be easier to just substitute as step 1.

Your initial simplification is wrong. Implementing the trig substitution right away, while assuming $\cos y>0$ for brevity, yields
$$\int \frac{2\sqrt{1- x^2}}{2 x\sqrt{1- x^2}+ 5} \, dx \stackrel{x=\sin t}= \int \frac{2\cos^2t}{2\sin t \cos t+5} \, dt$$
Hint for proceeding: what identities do you know that can be applied to $\cos^2t$ and $2\sin t\cos t$?

Thanks for your help.    What do you mean by identities?

$(\sin t + \cos t) ^2 = 1 + \sin 2t$

I mean trigonometric identities. Masd's answer shows what I was getting at.

Substitute $x=\frac t{\sqrt{1+t^2}}$
\begin{align}
\int \frac{2\sqrt{1- x^2}}{2 x\sqrt{1- x^2}+ 5}dx
=& \int \frac{2}{(1+t^2)(5t^2+2t +5)}dt\\
=&\ \int \frac{t+\frac25}{t^2+\frac25 t +1}-\frac t{1+t^2}\ dt
\end{align}
